# Can't run a task schedule in Laravel using cron job

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduler

we prepared functionality to run automatically, while it is working in the local server using the terminal but not in the server.

what is wrong with this cron command?

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/path_of_server/artisan schedule:run >> null 2>&1
```

Comment: There's documentation available on [Running The Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler)

Answer (score 0):

dev is missing in your command.
It should be like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/path_of_server/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```